# Mapping fragment error TimeZoneInfo Object to db EF Code First

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, telerik, dbcontext

I am using Teleriks WPF UI with the RadScheduleView, and I am having trouble mapping a custom appointment class to a database. I'm using a code first approach, and everything works fine when i create my custom resources, but the custom appointment class fails.

I get this innererror when i compile.

```
"\r\n(6,10) : error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:No mapping specified for properties Bokning.TimeZone in Set Bokning.\r\nAn Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:\r\n  Entity is type [TelerikWpfApp1.Bokning]\r\n"
```

This is my bokning class

```
class Bokning : Appointment
{
    public Bokning() { }
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Storage<Bokning>().id;
        }

        set
        {
            var storage = this.Storage<Bokning>();
            if (storage.id != value)
            {
                storage.id = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Id);
            }
        }
    }
    public override IAppointment Copy()
    {
        var customAppointment = new Bokning();
        customAppointment.CopyFrom(this);
        return customAppointment;
    }
    public override void CopyFrom(IAppointment other)
    {
        var customAppointment = other as Bokning;
        if (customAppointment != null)
        {
            this.Id = customAppointment.Id;
        }
        base.CopyFrom(other);
    }

}
```

This is my context

```
class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DBContext(): base("ADO Solutions")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Personal> Personal { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Jobb> Jobb { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Bokning> Bokning { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }


}
```

The Personal and Jobb classes work without a problem. But the bokning class is giving me trouble. I think there is a problem mappning the TimeZone attribute from the Appointment class. In the database the Bokning table gets created but not all the columns are there. I think it crashes cause the TimeZone attribute is a TimeZoneInfo object.

I think I need a way to map the TimeZoneInfo object as a string in the db, not even sure this is the problem though.

Edit: I might use the word map and mapping wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bokning>().Ignore(t => t.TimeZone);
```

to onModelCreating

makes it ignore the timezone property, which is fine. And it works now

Comment: But then you will lose the timezone as this will not add the timezone attribute/property to your db table. So far, i haven't found a better solution, then to store the timezone as string.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the `TimeZoneInfo.Id` property in your database. And then get the `TimeZoneInfo` with the `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()` method.